# A certain sum doubles in 7 years under compound interest, compounded annually. In how many years will the sum become four times itself?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is what I've tried so far:

http://i.snag.gy/X79I6.jpg

First I solved for the interest (*i*) that it would take to double a some of money (*x*) in 7 years. Then I took that interest, plugged it in, and solved for the amount of time it would take to quadruple any sum with that same interest rate.

However, this does not work; the numbers do not check properly. I've never taken a higher-level math course (just started college algebra), so I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix that.

Comment: Can you explain where the $(1 + \frac i{12})^{12}$ term comes from in your second line? Interest is compounded annually, but that term would arise if it were compounded monthly

Comment: @Mathmo123 you're right; I hadn't realized how the formula works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  If a certain sum doubles in seven years, then **any** sum will double in seven years: that's how compound interest works.  There is really no need to do any algebra at all.

---

OK, in response to comments, a bit more of a hint: if you start with a principal $P$ and the annual interest rate is $r$, then doubling in seven years means that
$$P(1+r)^7=2P\ .$$
How much would you have after seven years if you started with $2P$?

Comment: That much is clear from the OP's attempts

Comment: The interest rate is not given though, so I don't see how that would apply?

Comment: @Mathmo123 But my point is that all those attempts were totally unnecessary.

Comment: Ah I see what you're getting at now - you may want to clarify what you mean though.

Comment: I get it now; I could have divided both sides by *x* at the start. *facepalm*

Comment: @Ian it's even more straightforward than that. You don't need to do any algebra at all. If it takes $7$ years to double your money, how many years will it take to double it again?

Comment: OK, so after I fixed everything I got 14, which doesn't make sense to me. If it's compound interest, why would it be linear?

Comment: Right, with simple interest the amount of interest earned is the same every year (or every seven years).  With compound interest the ratio is the same every year.

Comment: Oh, OK. I think I get it now.